# Import Error of sorl.thumbnail in PythonAnyWhere site

Tags: python, python-import, importerror, sorl-thumbnail, pythonanywhere

I have `pip install sorl-thumbnail` in my site's virtual environment and when I try to `python manage.py syncdb` from `/home/myname/` I get the following error.

```
File "/home/myname/myProject/myApp/models.py", line 2, in <module>
     from sorl.thumbnail import ImageField
ImportError: No module named sorl.thumbnail
```

How do I rectify this?

Comment: have you activated the environment before running `python manage.py syncdb`?

Comment: what @Alik said.  Give us a shout if you're totally stuck, support@pythonanywhere.com

Comment: also make sure that you are working within your virtualenv when you are running your command